# pvc is not bound when use statefulset volumeClaimTemplates，localPV and WaitForFirstConsumer

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, statefulset

I want to use Local pv to provide storage for es statefulset, and Local pv needs to correspond to pod, so I try the following, Create a pv for each node local path (`mkdir -p /data/logging/elasticsearch/master`) create the corresponding storage class to match it and set the delay binding (WaitForFirstConsumer), and finally use helm to install es, volumeClaimTemplates is used in the template

1. create pv like this：

   ```yaml
   # pv-local.yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolume
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch--master-1
     labels:
       pvname: elasticsearch--master-1
   spec:
     capacity:
       storage: 30Gi
     volumeMode: Filesystem
     accessModes:
     - ReadWriteOnce
     persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     local:
       path: /data/logging/elasticsearch/master
     nodeAffinity:
       required:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
             operator: In
             values:
             - k8s1211
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolume
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch--master-2
     labels:
       pvname: elasticsearch--master-2
   spec:
     capacity:
       storage: 30Gi
     volumeMode: Filesystem
     accessModes:
     - ReadWriteOnce
     persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     local:
       path: /data/logging/elasticsearch/master
     nodeAffinity:
       required:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
             operator: In
             values:
             - k8s1212
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolume
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch--master-0
     labels:
       pvname: elasticsearch--master-0
   spec:
     capacity:
       storage: 30Gi
     volumeMode: Filesystem
     accessModes:
     - ReadWriteOnce
     persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     local:
       path: /data/logging/elasticsearch/master
     nodeAffinity:
       required:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
             operator: In
             values:
             - k8s1210
   ```
2. create storageclass like this：

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
   kind: StorageClass
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-logging
   provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
   volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
   reclaimPolicy: Retain
   ```
3. use helm install elasticsearch and helm creat statefulset like this：

   ```
   helm install -name es-master -f values-master.yaml -n logging .
   ```

   ```yaml
   kind: StatefulSet
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-master
     namespace: logging
     labels:
       app: elasticsearch-master
       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
       chart: elasticsearch
       heritage: Helm
       release: es-master
     annotations:
       esMajorVersion: '7'
       meta.helm.sh/release-name: es-master
       meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: logging
   spec:
     replicas: 3
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: elasticsearch-master
     template:
       metadata:
         name: elasticsearch-master
         creationTimestamp: null
         labels:
           app: elasticsearch-master
           chart: elasticsearch
           release: es-master
         annotations:
           configchecksum: 5b9873d870e8dac515e1c8de4df7144cc973664ca35a569294629d20fa21664
       spec:
         volumes:
           - name: elastic-certs
             secret:
               secretName: elastic-certs
               defaultMode: 493
           - name: esconfig
             configMap:
               name: elasticsearch-master-config
               defaultMode: 420
         initContainers:
           - name: configure-sysctl
             image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.3'
             command:
               - sysctl
               - '-w'
               - vm.max_map_count=262144
             resources: {}
             terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
             terminationMessagePolicy: File
             imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
             securityContext:
               privileged: true
               runAsUser: 0
         containers:
           - name: elasticsearch
             image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.3'
             ports:
               - name: http
                 containerPort: 9200
                 protocol: TCP
               - name: transport
                 containerPort: 9300
                 protocol: TCP
             env:
               - name: node.name
                 valueFrom:
                   fieldRef:
                     apiVersion: v1
                     fieldPath: metadata.name
               - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
                 value: >-
                   elasticsearch-master-0,elasticsearch-master-1,elasticsearch-master-2,
               - name: discovery.seed_hosts
                 value: elasticsearch-master-headless
               - name: cluster.name
                 value: elasticsearch
               - name: network.host
                 value: 0.0.0.0
               - name: cluster.deprecation_indexing.enabled
                 value: 'false'
               - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
                 value: '-Xmx1g -Xms1g'
               - name: node.data
                 value: 'false'
               - name: node.ingest
                 value: 'false'
               - name: node.master
                 value: 'true'
               - name: node.ml
                 value: 'true'
               - name: node.remote_cluster_client
                 value: 'true'
               - name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
                 valueFrom:
                   secretKeyRef:
                     name: elastic-auth
                     key: username
               - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
                 valueFrom:
                   secretKeyRef:
                     name: elastic-auth
                     key: password
             resources:
               limits:
                 cpu: '2'
                 memory: 2Gi
               requests:
                 cpu: '2'
                 memory: 2Gi
             volumeMounts:
               - name: elasticsearch-master
                 mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
               - name: elastic-certs
                 mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
               - name: esconfig
                 mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
                 subPath: elasticsearch.yml
             readinessProbe:
               exec:
                 command:
                   - bash
                   - '-c'
                   - >
                     set -e

                     # If the node is starting up wait for the cluster to be ready
                     (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" )

                     # Once it has started only check that the node itself is
                     responding

                     START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file


                     # Disable nss cache to avoid filling dentry cache when calling
                     curl

                     # This is required with Elasticsearch Docker using nss < 3.52

                     export NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE=no


                     http () {
                       local path="${1}"
                       local args="${2}"
                       set -- -XGET -s

                       if [ "$args" != "" ]; then
                         set -- "$@" $args
                       fi

                       if [ -n "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" ]; then
                         set -- "$@" -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
                       fi

                       curl --output /dev/null -k "$@" "http://127.0.0.1:9200${path}"
                     }


                     if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
                       echo 'Elasticsearch is already running, lets check the node is healthy'
                       HTTP_CODE=$(http "/" "-w %{http_code}")
                       RC=$?
                       if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then
                         echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with RC ${RC}"
                         exit ${RC}
                       fi
                       # ready if HTTP code 200, 503 is tolerable if ES version is 6.x
                       if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "200" ]]; then
                         exit 0
                       elif [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "503" && "7" == "6" ]]; then
                         exit 0
                       else
                         echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with HTTP code ${HTTP_CODE}"
                         exit 1
                       fi

                     else
                       echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" )'
                       if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" "--fail" ; then
                         touch ${START_FILE}
                         exit 0
                       else
                         echo 'Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" )'
                         exit 1
                       fi
                     fi
               initialDelaySeconds: 10
               timeoutSeconds: 5
               periodSeconds: 10
               successThreshold: 3
               failureThreshold: 3
             terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
             terminationMessagePolicy: File
             imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
             securityContext:
               capabilities:
                 drop:
                   - ALL
               runAsUser: 1000
               runAsNonRoot: true
         restartPolicy: Always
         terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
         dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
         automountServiceAccountToken: true
         securityContext:
           runAsUser: 1000
           fsGroup: 1000
         affinity:
           nodeAffinity:
             requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
               nodeSelectorTerms:
                 - matchExpressions:
                     - key: elasticsearch-logging
                       operator: In
                       values:
                         - 'true'
           podAntiAffinity:
             requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
               - labelSelector:
                   matchExpressions:
                     - key: app
                       operator: In
                       values:
                         - elasticsearch-master
                 topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
         schedulerName: default-scheduler
         enableServiceLinks: true
     volumeClaimTemplates:
       - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
         apiVersion: v1
         metadata:
           name: elasticsearch-master
           creationTimestamp: null
         spec:
           accessModes:
             - ReadWriteOnce
           resources:
             requests:
               storage: 30Gi
           storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
           volumeMode: Filesystem
         status:
           phase: Pending
     serviceName: elasticsearch-master-headless
     podManagementPolicy: Parallel
     updateStrategy:
       type: RollingUpdate
     revisionHistoryLimit: 10
   ```
4. then StatefulSet auto create the pvc ，but it not bound to pv，i don't no why？

   ```yaml
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0
     namespace: logging
     labels:
       app: elasticsearch-master
     finalizers:
       - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
   spec:
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 30Gi
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     volumeMode: Filesystem
   ---
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1
     namespace: logging
     labels:
       app: elasticsearch-master
     finalizers:
       - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
   spec:
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 30Gi
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     volumeMode: Filesystem
   ---
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2
     namespace: logging
     labels:
       app: elasticsearch-master
     finalizers:
       - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
   spec:
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 30Gi
     storageClassName: elasticsearch-logging
     volumeMode: Filesystem
   ```

I tried to create pvc manually, it still doesn't work, when I remove WaitForFirstConsumer, it can bind pv, but it can't correspond to node and pv, sometimes pod A binds pv2 when node 1, which is not what I want The result will also report an error because it does not match

I checked the official docs ([https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/](https://stackoverflow.com)) and it seems to be consistent with what I'm doing, so I don't know what's wrong?